# Search a post in Wordpress and load via AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have this structure in wordpress.

```
<input type="text" id="search_subject">
<button id="btn_search_subject">Send</button>

<div id="results_search"></div>
<button id="back">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

I wanna search a word and via AJAX load the first result in the div #results_search

I lookup some tutorials, but, I didn´t quite understand, some tutorials include all the coode in the functions.php file, and others divide the coding in the ajax.js file.

It could be a search just in the titles of the posts

Answer (score 1):

**Here is HTML code**

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search_posts" name="_posts" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>" id="ajax_url_input">
```

**Here is Jquery Code**

```
jQuery( "#search_posts" ).keyup( function() {
    var search_posts = jQuery(this).val();
    var ajax_url = jQuery('#ajax_url_input').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'search_data',
            search_posts: search_posts,
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
        },
        success:function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is PHP Function for Ajax**

```
function search_data() {
$search = '';
if(isset($_POST['search_posts'])){
    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'=> 'posts',
        'post_status'=> 'publish',
        's' => $_POST['search_posts']
    );
}
$services_data = get_posts( $args );
}
add_action('wp_ajax_search_data', 'search_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_data', 'search_data');
```

This code will search text in post title and in post content.